# Spaces in output firing sql query through command prompt

Tags: sql-server

I am firing a SQL query through command prompt

```
 H:\>sqlcmd -S cx-siscsqltest\sqlinst  -Q "select serverproperty('servername'), serverproperty('Edition'), SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion'), SERVERPROPERTY('Productlevel') "
```

The output is returning huge spaces, can you please help me remove those spaces? I have to use this output in xml

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561961/formatting-output-in-sqlcmd-mode or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33738433/how-to-format-sqlcmd-output maybe

Comment: Please provide an example of what you mean by "The output is returning huge spaces".

Comment: Have you tried casting your result to a smaller NVARCHAR ?

Comment: Note that SQL Server has full support for XML (`FOR XML AUTO`, `FOR XML PATH`) so you may be able to get the result you're after without further formatting.

Comment: @underscore- above command returns 4 col and 1 row , each data occupies 100 lines